# Push different object in an array with a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I have an element structured like this:

```
Element ->
[{values: arrayOfObject, key:'name1'}, ... ,{values: arrayOfObjectN, key:'nameN'}]  

arrayDiObject -> [Object1, Object2, ... , ObjectN]    //N = number of lines in my CSV

Object1 -> {x,y}
```

---

I have to take data from a big string:

`cityX#substanceX#cityY#substanceY#`

I thought to make it this way, but it seems like it pushes **always in the same array of objects**. If I put `oggetto = {values: arrayDateValue, key: key};` inside the d3.csv function, instead if I put outside the function it add me only empty objects.

Here is my code:

```
var final = new Array();
var oggetto;
var key;

function creaDati() {
    var newdate;
    var arrayDateValue = new Array();
    var selString = aggiungiElemento().split("#");
    //selString is an array with selString[0]: city, selString[1]: substance and so on..
    var citySelected = "";
    var substanceSelected = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < selString.length - 1; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            citySelected = selString[i];
        } else if (i % 2 !== 0) {
            substanceSelected = selString[i];
            key = citySelected + "#" + substanceSelected;

            d3.csv("/CSV/" + citySelected + ".csv", function(error, dataset) {
                dataset.forEach(function(d) {
                    arrayDateValue.push({
                        x: d.newdate,
                        y: d[substanceSelected]
                    });
                });
            });
            oggetto = {
                values: arrayDateValue,
                key: key
            };
            arrayDateValue = [];
            final.push(oggetto);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: The output is unclear. Moreover, you probably have a typo in your code: http://prntscr.com/bh6o9t "citySelected" vs "cittySelected" . Can you please be clearer about the input, the goal and the desired output? (also, what is aggiungiElemento() ? can you please show us that function aswell?)

Comment: It was a typo: I translate it from Italian and I forgot, pardon.
aggiungiElemento() return the string city#substance#city#substance#... and i will split it with the # char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED-**
The problem is about d3.csv which is a asynchronous function, it add in the array when it finish to run all the other code.

I make an XMLHttpRequest for each csv file and it works.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make the if statement for the city and then for the key, which you seem to be doing wrong since you want the pair indexes to be the keys and the not pair to be the city, and you are doing the opposite. And then you need to have the d3.csv and push the objects outside of the if statement, otherwise in your case you are just adding elements with citySelected="".

Try something like :

```
    for(var i = 0; i < selString.length -1; i+=2){
                                cittySelected = selString[i];
                                substanceSelected = selString[i+1];
                                key = citySelected + "#" + substanceSelected;

                                d3.csv("/CSV/"+citySelected+".csv", function(error, dataset){
                                    dataset.forEach(function(d){                                                       
                                        arrayDateValue.push({x: d.newdate, y: d[substanceSelected]});  
                                    });                            
                                });
                                oggetto = {values: arrayDateValue, key: key};
                                arrayDateValue = [];
                               final.push(oggetto);
                            }
```

It's is not the best way to do it, but it is clearer that what you are following, i think.

Answer (score 0):

In the `if(i % 2 == 0) { citySelected = ... }` and `else if(i % 2 !== 0) { substanceSelected = ... }`  `citySelected` and `substanceSelected` will never come together.

The values should be in **one** statement:

```
if(...) { citySelected = ...; substanceSelected = ...; }
```

The string can be splitted into **pairs**

`city1#substance1, city2#substance2, ...`

with a **regex** `(\w{1,}#\w{1,}#)`.

Empty the `arrayDateValue` **after** the if-statement.

---

**Hint**:

```js
var str = "cityX#substanceX#cityY#substanceY#";

function createArr(str) {
 var obj = {};
 var result = [];
 var key = "";
 // '', cityX#substanceX, '', cityYsubstanceY
 var pairs = str.split(/(\w{1,}#\w{1,}#)/g);  

    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
     if(i % 2 !== 0) {
      key = pairs[i];

      // d3 stuff to create values

      obj = {
                // Values created with d3 placeholder
    values: [{x: "x", y: "y"}], 
                // Pair
    key: key
   };

   result.push(obj);
     }

     // Here should be values = [];
    }

 return result;
}

var r = createArr(str);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this;

```js
var str = "cityX#substanceX#cityY#substanceY",
    arr = str.split("#").reduce((p,c,i,a) => i%2 === 0 ? p.concat({city:c, key:a[i+1]}) : p,[]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```